# Getting message built-in method append of list object when making list in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to build a list that contains the second element of the list within a list. I've first scraped some links and stored in `links_2016`

```
for i in links_2016:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(i)
    path = parsed[2] 
    pathlist = path.split("/")
    list_pathlist.append(pathlist)

#get the months
months = []
for i in range(0,44): #there are 44 elements in list_pathlist
    list_pathlist[i][2] #get the second element 
    months.append
```

but then when I print months I get built-in method messages in the list:

```
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
'06'
<built-in method append of list object at 0x103c85170>
```

and then after this when I do `print months` I only get `[]`, which means that there is something wrong with the result.

I need to also count the elements within the months list, so I'd like to learn how I can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it work now

```
for i in links_2016:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(i)
    path = parsed[2] 
    pathlist = path.split("/")
    list_pathlist.append(pathlist)

#get the months
months = []
for i in range(0,len(list_pathlist)): #there are 44 elements in list_pathlist 
    months.append(list_pathlist[i][2]) #you are actually getting the third item
                                       #since list indice start at 0, if you want the second item do [1]
print(months)
```

to count the elements in the months list do `len(months)`